# Python: How do I get my function to repeat until asked to cancel?

Tags: python, function, loops, while-loop, python-3.3

I just started learning Python. Basically I just want to repeat the loop once if answer is yes, or break out of the loop if answer is no. The return True/False doesn't go back to the while loop?

```
def userinfo():
    while true:
    first_name=input("Enter your name here:")
    last_name=input("Enter your last name:")
    phonenum=input("Enter your phone number here")
    inputagain=rawinput("Wanna go again")
    if inputagain == 'no':
        return False

userinfo()
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23294658/asking-the-user-for-input-until-they-give-a-valid-response)

Comment: `return` causes the function to immediately end, you expect it to go back around?

Comment: `True` is capitalized.  Your while loop body needs to be indented.  If it's python3 then use `input()`, if it's python2 use `raw_input`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `while true:` use a variable instead.

Such as

```
while inputagain != 'no':
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of looping forever and terminating explicitly, you could have an actual condition in the loop.  First assume that the user wants to go again by starting `again` as 'yes'

```
again = 'yes'
while again != 'no':
    # ... request info ...
    again = input("Wanna go again?: ")
```

though this while condition is a bit weak, if the user enters `N`, `n`, `no` or ever `no` with space around it, it will fail.  Instead you could check if the first letter is an `n` after lowercasing the string

```
while not again.lower().startswith('n'):
```

You could stick to your original style and make sure the user always enters a yes-like or no-like answer with some extra logic at the end of your loop

```
while True:
    # ... request info ...
    while True:
        again = input("Wanna go again?: ").lower()
        if again.startswith('n'):
            return # exit the whole function
        elif again.startswith('y'):
            break # exit just this inner loop
```